# Clear complete Table for custom entity via App?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api, shopware6-app

Is it possible to clear the complete table via an App through the API for a custom entity?
I tried a DELETE but get an error message: Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET, POST)
The documentation states, that its not needed to set the permission in the xml for the own entity. And I can see that also the delete permission is set when looking at the permissions from the App.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [sync endpoint](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/0612cb5d960ef-bulk-edit-entities) to mass-delete records but you will still need the ids for all the records to be deleted. There is no way to truncate a table via the api if that is what you're looking for.